# load data local infile - select ignoring last column

Tags: mysql, select, csv, load-data-infile

I'm trying to import csv file into mysql database using **load data local infile**

My csv file looks like this:

```
1;Lubos;Chrapna;92;muz;Topolcany
2;Branislav;Grecni;28;muz;Topolcianky
3;David;Forgac;57;muz;Hronsky Benadik
4;Imrich;Doci;58;muz;Kosice
```

table I wanna put this cvs file in looks like this:

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DIM_zakaznik (
   id int(5),
   meno varchar(15),
   priezvisko varchar(15),
   vek int(15),
   pohlavie varchar(15),
   bydlisko varchar(15))
```

and my query looks like this:

```
    load data local infile 'dim_zakaznik.csv' into table DIM_zakaznik 
    fields terminated by ';'
    enclosed by '\n'
    lines terminated by '\n';
```

it works just fine and when I look at that table in phpMyAdmin everything looks OK but my problem is that when I'm trying to run select it's ignoring last column (called 'bydlisko')

for example I try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM `dim_zakaznik` WHERE `bydlisko`='Topolcany'
```

and all it does it just says: *"MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0184 sec)"*

it shouldn't be empty result right?
It's not working only with that last column and I have no idea why.
When I tried it before with those columns plus I added another one column (that column was last in table) it ignored that other column (that was last column in table)

I'd really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you do a 'select *' is all the data there? What if you do a 'select * from table where bydlisko like 'topolcany'?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use **"enclosed by '\n'"** section in your query, as your fields in **CSV** are not delimited by '\n'. Try removing that section, then run your query again.

Also, just as a remark, be sure that you don't truncate column data. Last column is 15 chars long. Is that enough for 15-letters word ? (Varchar takes one more byte for length, so there would be necessarily 16 for value "Hronsky Benadik").

Answer (score 0):

So an old one, but I just stumbled across this and noticed there's no good answers to it.
I see this happen every single time I assign and then grade an "upload csv homework" in a database class. What does your .csv file look like, you didn't show it here.

if this query you showed does NOT work:

```
SELECT * FROM `dim_zakaznik` WHERE `bydlisko`='Topolcany'
```

then I feel the need to ask, does this query work:

```
SELECT * FROM `dim_zakaznik` WHERE `bydlisko`=' Topolcany'
```

If so then remember: "spaces are for humans", and adjust your .csv file accordingly. (also checking LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' will help if your table is getting formatting issues.